# changing /etc/profile does nothing to root PATH

Tags: environment-variables, redhat-enterprise-linux

rhel 5 root has `/bin/bash` for shell. I removed `pathmunge /usr/local/sbin` from `/etc/profile`. There is no `/usr/local/sbin` in `/etc/profile.d/*` `/etc/bashrc` `/root/.bashrc` `/root/.bash_profile` `/root/.profile`

After reboot, `/usr/loca/bin` still shows up in the root path.

How does rhel 5 set default `PATH` for root? Which config file has `/usr/local/sbin`?

Comment: `/etc/paths`? `/etc/paths.d/*`?

Comment: Any reason not to go ahead and modify root's `.bashrc`? Also, please reformat your question - it is a little difficult to read in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

bash has a default value for `PATH` that is built into the binary. On RHEL it is set to `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`.  Since `/etc/profile` and the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` never explicitly set `PATH` (they instead modify it with constructs like `PATH=$PATH:/somedir`), you're left with that built-in `PATH` as a starting point.

If you'd like get rid of this, you have to explicitly set `PATH`.  I suggest doing it by putting

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

At the top of `/etc/profile`.